# SQL get data from one table with joined ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
ProductID   | JoinedProductID
------------|----------------
12          | 
13          | 12
14          | 12
15          | 12
```

I have one table with products as the example above. I connected some products to the main product (#12) with a joint ID. 
I would like to display -all- of these products in a subselection -except- the product that I'm currently viewing.

My approach so far has been like this example but I'm not able to solve my problem, this will only display subproducts (13,14,15).

```
SELECT t1.*<br>
FROM<br>
  Product t1<br>
  INNER JOIN Product t2 ON (t1.joinedProductID = t2.ProductID)<br>
WHERE<br>
  t1.joinedProductID = 12(request from DB)<br> OR <br>
  t2.ProductID = 12(querystring request)
```

Comment: Is this a subquery? Or what you mean by 'subselection'? Share the complete query if so

Comment: Please add an example of your desired output

Comment: Am I missing something. Just the join with where SomeID <> SomeIdFromWhereItComesFrom

Comment: The way your SQL is currently written means the first row (Product ID = 12) will be excluded as it has no value for the JoinedProductID, this is due to the INNER JOIN condition as it gets applied before your filters in the WHERE clause. Are you trying to display the rows with ProductId =12 and JoinedProductID = 12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying this off the top of my head but what about

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Product t1 INNER JOIN Product t2 ON t2.ProductID = CASE WHEN t1.JoinedProduct IS NULL THEN t1.ProductID ELSE t1.JoinedProductID END
WHERE t2.ProductID = 12
```

Comment: This worked, excellent! Just had to add this in the WHERE clause
`WHERE t2.ProductID = 12 AND  t1.ProductID<>14(from querystring request)`

Comment: Could you please provide an example of using coalesce() in this query Gordon Linoff?

Comment: @akc42 after testing your solution now there is a problem, if I click on productID (13) "... WHERE t2.ProductID = 13" DB will not render any of these sub products, all products joined on ProductID 12.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct - I was just doing it on the fly.  Espen S. Replace the Case Statement with COALESCE(t1.JoinedProduct,t1.ProductID)